# How to secure tomcat's manager with ssl

Tags: ssl, tomcat

How can I secure tomcat's application manager with ssl ? I already have the certificates for the site.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the admin app inside a SSL connector.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/ssl-howto.html

Answer (score 3):

You could try adding user-data-constraints in tomcat manager's web.xml.  That might do the trick:

```
<user-data-constraint>
  <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
```

Maybe insert them before the /security-contraint closing tag in the **HTML Manager commands** section of that web.xml:

Answer (score 1):

you can use nginx or apache in front of your tomcat to control access easily.

Comment: I tried with apache and mod_proxy, but when it redirects to the manager app it goes plain-text.

Comment: check this: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Using+Apache+with+mod_proxy